# Assigning Boolean Values to html Table Entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to attach a hidden value of either 0 or 1 to each entry in a table. If the value is a 0 the entry will be colored Red, and if the value is a 1, the entry will be colored green.

I tried implementing this using filters and creating two different classes 'success' and 'danger' if the class 'success was added to the entry then the entry would be colored green and for 'danger' it would be colored red. I was able to get this to work by using a filter that checks for the string "True" or "False" in the entry. If the String is "True" then it adds the success class if if it is false it adds the danger class. This works however I now want to expand this idea so that every entry will have an assigned boolean.

I am looking for some help on how to do this.

This is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    .success { background:green; }
.danger { background:red; }
  </style>
  <!-- TODO: Missing CoffeeScript 2 -->

  <script type="text/javascript">


    $(function(){

$('tr:has(td:contains("True"))').addClass('success');
$('tr:has(td:contains("False"))').addClass('danger');

    });

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr><td>True</td></tr>
    <tr><td>True</td></tr>
    <tr><td>False</td></tr>
    <tr><td>True</td></tr>
    <tr><td>False</td></tr>
    <tr><td>True</td></tr>
    <tr><td>True</td></tr>
</table>

  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "rm3Hz"
      }], "*")
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But do you want to assign a value other than the color class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you add an `id` to your table so you can access it directly.

After that we get the array of `tr`. Also I can recommend here you validate that this array is of the same size than your `results` array. Just for good measure.

Then we can just iterate over this array using jQuery's `each` function.

```js
let status = [false , true , false , true , false , false , true , true ];

$('#mainTable tr').each((i,tr) => {
  if(status[i])
    $(tr).addClass('success');
  else
    $(tr).addClass('danger');
})
```

```css
.success { background:green; }
    .danger { background:red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table id='mainTable' width="100%">
    <tr><td>True</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
</table>

  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "rm3Hz"
      }], "*")
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you Gerardo that makes a lot of sense to me. I've attempted to implement your code my version is now the version shown in the edit strangely it is still not functioning properly I am curious where I made my mistake

Comment: I determined the solution I thank you alot for your help!

Comment: looks like it worked out jajaja. Hope you can upvote and accept if it did. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work...

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr><td>True</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td style="display:none">0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td style="display:none">1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td style="display:none">0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td style="display:none">0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td><td style="display:none">1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td style="display:none">0</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an own property (e.g. data-boolean) to your cells.

```js
//get all elements with attribute data-boolean and convert the HTML collection into an array
var aCells = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[data-boolean]")); 

//Loop the elements and add the styleclass
aCells.forEach(function(v,i){
 if(v.getAttribute("data-boolean") === "true"){
    v.classList.add("success");
  }
  
  if(v.getAttribute("data-boolean") === "false"){
    v.classList.add("danger");
  }
});
```

```css
.success {
  background: green;
}

.danger {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td data-boolean="true">True</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-boolean="false">False</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```